# Lower central series for $GL(2,\mathbb{C})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

how can I write the  lower central series (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_series#Lower_central_series) for $GL(2,\mathbb{C})$ ?

I appreciate any help, because I do not clearly see where to start, There are too many elements to conjugate here, unlike finite groups where finding the lower central series is doable.

Thanks !

Comment: See Example 1.5 and Exercise 1.6 here. http://hilbert.math.unt.edu/downloads/teaching/5520-10/solvable-nilpotent.pdf They might help.

Comment: For any $n \ge 2$ and any field $K$, apart from the small cases $n=2$, $|K|=2$ or $3$, ${\rm SL}(n,K)$ is perfect, and ${\rm GL}(n,K)/{\rm SL}(n,K) \cong K^*$ is abelian, so the lower central series is just ${\rm GL}(n,K) > {\rm SL}(n,K)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

$$\pmatrix{1 & -\lambda/3 \\ 0 & 1} \pmatrix{2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1/2} \pmatrix{1 & \lambda/3 \\ 0 & 1}\pmatrix{1/2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2} = \pmatrix{1 & \lambda \\ 0 & 1}.$$

Now note that ${SL}_2$ is generated by transvection matrices.